# Year calendar in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I need to do the calendar look like this link

http://www.homelifeweekly.com/wp-content/uploads/calendar-year-printable.jpg

Can I do that? If not, any ways to do?

Answer (score 1):

I think you can do what you want with the [Flextras Calendar Control.](https://www.flextras.com)  It looks like a pretty solid and skinnable control that you should be able to rock.  Quite affordable as well.

Comment: +! for promoting us.  Here is a sample that demonstrates a year view w/ our component: https://www.flextras.com/Calendar/Samples/YearDisplay/